# Weird PHP responses in subdomain

Tags: php, database, get, request, response

I am trying to make a website that echos out a number or a word based on some conditions. I connected it to my database, but it always echos out 2 (user not found), instead of yes100 (password and username correct).
The weird thing is, it works on my main domain, where it outputs yes100, but here it just can not do that for some reason.
I am sure my database details are correct, and I have uploaded the file where it should be.
This is my code (not secure at all, but it is for personal use only.)

```
$result = $link->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Outputting the rows
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $password = $row['password'];
        $salt = $row['salt'];
        $plain_pass = $_GET['password'];
        $stored_pass = md5(md5($salt).md5($plain_pass));

        function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
        {
            if (headers_sent() === false)
            {
                header('Location: ' . $url, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
            }
        exit();
        }

        if($stored_pass != $row['password'])
        {
            echo "BLAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA";
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "yes"; // Correct pass
        }

        if (strlen($row['hwid']) > 1)
        {
            if ($hwid != $row['hwid'])
            {
                echo "0"; // Wrong
            }
            else
            {
                echo "100"; // Correct
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE ". $tables ." SET hwid='$hwid' WHERE username='$user'";
            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql))
            {
                echo "rdy"; // HWID Set
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "4"; // Else errors
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
} 
else
{
    echo "2"; // User doesn't exist
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you having data in database? you are zero in num rows thats why it returns zero

Comment: `$result = $link->query($sql);` Make sure this actually returns data. What is `$sql`?

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5 for password hashing! [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even states: _"Warning - It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: You're code will also throw a fatal (for trying to redeclare the function Redirect()) if the database returns more than one record and the while loop iterates more than once. Put the `function Redirect(...) { ... }` before the loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to give the user the permissions. It works now. Thanks everyone.